# How to force the subscriber to read the latest message in a topic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, My apologies if the question is unclear, I'll elaborate here:

I have a node that publishes real-time image to a topic at 30Hz.

I am writing another node that subscribes to this topic and processes the image (find a target in the image).

The processing time varies, sometimes the algorithm can process images at 10Hz, sometimes 5Hz.

I want my node to process a frame, and after it finishes, get the latest frame and process that.

I tried setting queue_size of my publisher to 1, I thought that would force all old messages to be dropped. However that didn't work. My callback is just processing the old frames that's remained in the pipeline(whose size I don't know how to set)

Can someone help me with this? I'm using python.  I'm trying to build a sampling port rather than a queuing port, if this explanation helps.

Another question:

1. Does ros spawns a new thread for callback function every time a new message is available in a topic?
2. How many buffers/pipes are there in a publisher->topic->subscriber system?

Thank you!

Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278405/how-to-force-the-subscriber-to-read-the-latest-message-in-a-topic?/) by [nickzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33071/nickzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the queue size of your subscriber, not your publisher to 1. According to the [rospy Subscriber API docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html), the queue size defaults to infinite if not explicitly set, which would explain the behavior you're seeing.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33071/nickzhang/) on 2018-01-15**:
Hi Stefan. I tried the method proposed and I still have similar problems. could you look into https://answers.ros.org/question/279791/unexpected-delay-in-subscriber-subscriber-not-getting-latest-message/    Thanks!